# SQL query doesn't find cities that begin with č, ć, š, ž, etc

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, character-encoding

My SQL query doesn't find cities that begin with for instance č, but does find cities which have č in their name but begin with regular English letters.

The City column in the database is of nvarchar type.

What is the solution for this problem?

I am using an SQLite database.

```
    cmdSQLite = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT RegistrationNumber, DocumentName, 
    Performer, BuiltYear, ReferatCardNumber , City, Municipalities , StreetName 
    FROM Geotest WHERE LOWER (City) = @City", connectionSQLite);

    SQLiteParameter parameterCity = new SQLiteParameter();
    parameterCity.Value = comboBoxCitySearch.Text.ToLower();
    parameterCity.ParameterName = "@City";
    cmdSQLite.Parameters.Add(parameterCity);
```

Comment: First letter of a city is in upper case. Maybe in your query only lower cases are used?

Comment: I put city first to lower case, it is not problem.

Comment: i think you should wrap both parts of the case equality with either upper or lower...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
parameterCity.Value = comboBoxCitySearch.Text;
```

Dont use C# function comboBoxCitySearch.Text.ToLower(); Just in SQL use:

```
WHERE LOWER(City) = LOWER(@City)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem might be related to unicode string in SQL Server. This might help

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239530

> When dealing with Unicode string constants in SQL Server you must
>   precede all Unicode strings with a capital letter N, as documented in
>   the SQL Server Books Online topic "Using Unicode Data". The "N" prefix
>   stands for National Language in the SQL-92 standard, and must be
>   uppercase. If you do not prefix a Unicode string constant with N, SQL
>   Server will convert it to the non-Unicode code page of the current
>   database before it uses the string.

UPDATE: My mistake, I did not read the question correctly, I thought we were talking about SQL Server. Reading the SQL Lite documentation, http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18

> The default configuration of SQLite only supports case-insensitive
>   comparisons of ASCII characters. The reason for this is that doing
>   full Unicode case-insensitive comparisons and case conversions
>   requires tables and logic that would nearly double the size of the
>   SQLite library. The SQLite developers reason that any application that
>   needs full Unicode case support probably already has the necessary
>   tables and functions and so SQLite should not take up space to
>   duplicate this ability.

Comment: The OP is asking about SQLite, not SQL Server.